# loop through the batch image loader pytorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch

Let say I have batch with

> imgs = torch.Size([128, 1, 28, 28])

if I want to loop through the each image

```
for img in imgs:
   print(img.shpae) -> torch.Size([1, 28, 28])
```

if I want to get a  torch.Size([1,1, 28, 28]) for each image what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the tensor initially to a shape of `[128, 1, 1, 28, 28]`

```py
# tensor.resize_((`new_shape`))    
imgs.resize_((128, 1, 1, 28, 28))
```

No when you loop through each image, will be of the desired shape [1, 1, 28, 28].

Secondly, if you don't want to change the original data, reshape each image individually

```py
# tensor.resize_((`new_shape`))    
img.resize_((1, 1, 28, 28))
```

Have a look at the PyTorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.resize_)

Answer (score 1):

[unsqueeze](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze) Just pass dim, In which position you want to add one extra singleton dimension.

```py
imgs = torch.zeros([128, 1, 28, 28])

# dim (int) – the index at which to insert the singleton dimension
imgs.unsqueeze_(dim = 1)

imgs.shape
>>> torch.Size([128, 1, 1, 28, 28])
```